# Passport local authentication: deseralizeUser never called

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, passport.js

I'm testing passport-local authentication in a test app but I can't understand why deserializeUser is not called when sending a post request with Postman but never called when the post request comes from my front end (Vuejs).
I guess there's something wrong with my way of managing session but I don't know what... Could anyone help me to understand?

Vue frontend:

```
export default {    
        name: "Login",    
        methods: {    
            login: (e) => {    
                e.preventDefault();  
                let username = "user1";
                let password = "password";    
                let login = () => {    
                    let data = {    
                        username: username,    
                        password: password
                    };    
                    axios.post("http://localhost:5000/api/users", data)    
                    .then((response) => {    
                        console.log("Logged in");    
                        router.push("/");    
                    })    
                    .catch((errors) => {    
                        console.log("Cannot log in");
                    });    
                };    
                login();
            }    
        }    
    }
```

Node backend:

```
app.use(cookieSession({  
    name: 'mysession',
    keys: ['vueauthrandomkey'],
    maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());`

passport-config.js
`passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    function(username, password, done) {    
      if(User[0].name == username) {        
        return done(null, JSON.stringify(User[0]));
      }
      else {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
      }
    }
  ));

  passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user);    
  });  
  passport.deserializeUser((user, done) => { // never called if request from Vuejs, no problem if the request is sent through Postam 
    done(null, user);
  });
```

Router:

```
router.post('/',  
  passport.authenticate('local', { 
    successRedirect: './',
    failureRedirect: '/',
    failureFlash: false 
  })
);
```

If successRedirect:

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.isAuthenticated()); // true if Postman, false if vuejs
    res.send('welcome !!!');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After browsing the entire web, I finally found the solution.
First I had to explicity ask axios to use credentials:

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true; // in the frontend
```

This config produced a CORS issue. To fix it I had to set my cors middleware as following server side:

```
app.use(cors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:8080', // frontend base url
    credentials: true
}));
```

And now it's working.
Hope it will save time to people facing the same issue...